# create a c programming IDE app with flutter

Tags: c, flutter, ide

which dependency can help me to run c programming language and show me the result. Creating c programming IDE is possible with flutter or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for syntax highlighting:-

- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_highlight

For compiling C though you can use Online Compiler APIs like:-

- https://sphere-engine.com/compilers
- https://www.jdoodle.com/compiler-api/
- https://www.hackerearth.com/docs/wiki/developers/v4/
- https://github.com/Jaagrav/CodeX-API

For emulating the terminal you can use Xterm: https://pub.dev/packages/xterm

Comment: is there any offline compiling system?

Comment: @RaihanHossain Maybe you could use Xterm to compile C programs offline using GCC.

Comment: how to use gcc in my flutter app

Comment: @RaihanHossain Your best option is to use an Online Compiler.  Many app do this already like Decoder on the Play Store.

Comment: I need offline. do you how to use gcc  in flutterr app.

Comment: @RaihanHossain I found a package: https://pub.dev/packages/ccompilers but I can't say for sure if it is relevant to your project.